# How to deploy Angular 17 with SSR with Docker?

Tags: angular, docker

## Minimal Example

Setting up a new Angular 17 project (Node 18) as follows:

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli@17
$ ng update @angular/core@17 @angular/cli@17
$ npm update

$ ng new example
stylesheets? $ SCSS
SSR? $ yes
$ cd example
$ ng serve
```

Connects just fine on `localhost:4200`.

Deploying it with Docker does not work, because all the example Dockerfiles expect older Angular versions without SSR.

**Seriously, guys. Before giving an answer try actually creating an Angular 17 SSR project and try if it works with your Dockerfile.**

## Docker Failures

I tried following these suggestions (remember to replace as necessary e.g.the node version `node:12-slim` by `node:18-slim`, the project name `sample-angular-app` by the project name `example`, doing the ports correctly etc.):

- https://dev.to/marwan01/deploy-an-angular-app-using-google-cloud-run-3p4a (there is no `server.js`)
- https://dev.to/rodrigokamada/creating-and-running-an-angular-application-in-a-docker-container-40mk (builds but no connection possible - just gives the NGIX default page).
- https://levioconsulting.com/insights/how-to-dockerize-an-angular-application-with-nginx/ (builds but no connection possible {connection reset} - and completely rebuilds the application on each docker run instead of only once).
- https://blog.stackademic.com/deploy-your-angular-app-with-docker-and-nginx-a5b0a3c1d06b (the Dockerfile has a syntax error, and when built cannot connect {connection reset})
- https://plainenglish.io/blog/how-to-dockerize-angular-application-3cd67e963832 (cannot connect {just gives the NGIX default page}, but at least it only builds once)
- https://github.com/coltenkrauter/angular-ssr-example/blob/stable/Dockerfile.ssr (expects pre-Angular 17 SSR, needs to be rewritten, then no connection {refused to connect})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app/src
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY --from=build /app/src/dist/PROJECT_NAME/server ./
CMD node server.mjs
EXPOSE 4000
```

#### Docker invocation

```
docker build . -t PROJECT_NAME -f Dockerfile
docker run -d PROJECT_NAME -p 8080:4000
```

#### Notes

- Replace `PROJECT_NAME` by the project name.
- Need to use `node:18` to support Angular 17.
- Need to copy from `dist/PROJECT_NAME/server` to get the version that can be served.
- Need to serve `server.mjs`, there is no `server.js`.
- Need to make sure the ports are mapped correctly.
- `4000` is the default port set in `server.ts`, see the line `const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;` in there. Of course one can define another port either by editing the `server.ts` or setting the `PORT` environment variable, but I kept it simple here.
- `8080` is the port where one can see the project in the browser at `http://localhost:8080/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM node:20.10.0-alpine As builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/site.com/frontend
COPY ../package*.json /usr/src/site.com/frontend
RUN npm ci
COPY ../ .
RUN npm run build -c production
CMD ["node", "./docker/dist/frontend/server/server.mjs"]
```

It starts on default port - 4000. And u can use nginx.

Answer (score -1):

Your app is written in TypeScript, but your Dockerfile is made for JavaScript apps. Have a look at [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-tooling-in-5-minutes.html) on how to compile TypeScript to JavaScript. If you want a tutorial to follow, check out [this one](https://dev.to/rodrigokamada/creating-and-running-an-angular-application-in-a-docker-container-40mk).

Comment: The TypeScript is compiled just fine. The point is that there **exists no `server.js`**, so the Dockerfile is wrong. So the question is how to get a correct Dockerfile.

Comment: When you compile your project normally (not in a container), does `server.js` exist there?

Comment: Of course not. It's Angular 17, SSR, TypeScript. So you get `dist/<project_name>/server/server.mjs`.