Angular - Deployment with SSR to AWS
I have an app built with Angular 18 with SSR enabled. I built it using ng build and deployed it by copying everything from dist/projectname/browser to an AWS bucket. The app is accessible online, however, I have new bugs that didn't exist locally on the online version.
Is this the way to deploy an Angular app with SSR on AWS or is there a better way?

Copying the browser folder to a web server is a client-side rendering approach. The SSR approach would be to start the built NodeJS server located in dist/projectname/server.

One approach to do a SSR deployment to AWS is with docker, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77850159
